# How to loop array of pointers to characters

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

Is there any way to loop array of character pointers? I was able to get the number of items in **args but how to get number of its each element so we can print its characters. As we can see each element column dimension differs. So is there any way in C to loop this?

```
int main()
{
    
    char *argv_c1[3] = {"cat","f.txt",NULL};
    char *argv_c2[2]={"sort",NULL};
    char *argv_c3[2]={"uniq",NULL};
    char *argv_c4[3]={"grep","day",NULL};
    char *argv_c5[3]={"wc","-l",NULL};

    char **args[]={argv_c1, argv_c2, argv_c3, argv_c4, argv_c5};

    unsigned long int total = sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]);
    printf("ld\n",total);
    
    for(int i=0;i<total;i++)
    {
        //how to loop argv_c1, argv_c2 ... argv_c5 ?
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `total` is what you expect?

Comment: @ScottHunter Why would it not be? However, for the *elements* of `args`, you can no longer use such syntax, because they're just pointers: each of the `argv_c*` arrays will have ***decayed*** into a pointer. The term, "decay", is used because information has been lost - that info is the array's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop over the elements of `args[i]`:

```
for(int j=0; args[i][j]!=NULL; j++)
```